# Why I get error 'Cannot set property '0' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, object

I do not understand why I can not create a new object

the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

I got error on the line code.  `this.gameAnimals[i] = {};`

```
this = Game;
gameAnimals[0] = 'frog';
```

so why I have error ?
Many Thanks.

```
var Game = {
    init: function(){
        this.property1 = 1;
        this.property2 = 2;
        this.property3 = 3;
        this.property1000 = 1000;
    },

     cons: function(gameAnimals){

        for(var i = 0; i < gameAnimals.length; i++){
             this.gameAnimals[i] = {};
        }
     },    
};

var gameAnimals = ['frog', 'lion', 'cat'];
Game.cons(gameAnimals);
```

Comment: `this` cannot be set explicitly that way. You can't do `this = Game;`

Comment: Your `Game` object hasn't got a `gameAnimals` property, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the zero-th element of `this.gameAnimals`.

However, `this.gameAnimals` doesn't exist, since the `Game` object doesn't have a private member `gameAnimals`.  Hence it's `undefined`, which you then try to set a property on.

I think you may simply mean `gameAnimals`, without prefixing it with `this`.  (Alternatively, you'll need to create `this.gameAnimals` first if that's what you really meant.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `gameAnimals` is declared after you try to assign values to it in the for loop. Try defining the array first.